# Text to Voice for Keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I created a small Softkeyboard for Android Studio and now want to add Speech to Text, but I am getting this error when I start the application in the logcat:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5174)
```

The Keyboard on itself and the Speech to Text on itself worked just fine.
Source Code:

```
package edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
        import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
        import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
        import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
        import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;


public class OrthKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    public static SpeechInnerClass SpeechInnerClass;




    private  boolean isCaps = false;
    public static String auto_word ="";



    //Press Ctrl+O


    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard,null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this,R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        SpeechInnerClass = new SpeechInnerClass();




        return kv;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPress(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int i) {

    }

   @Override
    public void onKey(int i, int[] ints) {

        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        playClick(i);
      //  MainActivity.count ++;
       if(i==-4222522|i==-4222521|i==-4222523|i==-4222525){
       if(i==-4222522){
           ic.commitText("Case 2",1);
       }
       if(i==-4222521){
           ic.commitText("Case 1",1);
       }
       if(i==-4222523){

           ic.commitText("Case 3",1);
       }

       if(i==-4222525){
           SpeechInnerClass.startVoiceInput();

           ic.commitText(SpeechInnerClass.output,1);
       }

       }
        else {
           switch (i) {
               case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                   ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                   break;
               case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                   isCaps = !isCaps;
                   keyboard.setShifted(isCaps);
                   kv.invalidateAllKeys();
                   break;
               case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                   ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                   break;
               default:
                   char code = (char) i;


                   if (Character.isLetter(code) && isCaps)
                       code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                   ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);


                   SettingsActivity.count++;
                   if ((char) i == ' ') {
                       auto_word = "";
                   }
                   if (96 < i && i < 123) {
                       auto_word = auto_word + (char) i;
                   }

           }
       }

    }

    private void playClick(int i) {

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch(i)
        {
            case 32:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            case 10:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
                break;
            default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence charSequence) {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }



    public static class SpeechInnerClass extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
        public static CharSequence output = "Test";
        private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
        private ImageButton mSpeakBtn;
        public boolean voice = false;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            if(voice=true){
                startVoiceInput();
            }
        }

        public void startVoiceInput() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, How can I help you?");
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                        ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                        output=(result.get(0));
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Full Logcat:

```
2019-07-14 13:23:02.202 12121-12121/? D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2019-07-14 13:23:02.211 12121-12121/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2019-07-14 13:23:02.214 12121-12121/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2019-07-14 13:23:02.216 12121-12121/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2019-07-14 13:39:26.230 12121-12121/? I/dcustomkeyboar: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-07-14 13:39:26.247 12121-12121/? E/dcustomkeyboar: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2019-07-14 13:39:26.247 12121-12121/? W/dcustomkeyboar: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-07-14 13:39:26.339 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard I/dcustomkeyboar: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-07-14 13:39:26.451 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard W/dcustomkeyboar: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-07-14 13:39:26.461 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard I/chatty: uid=10132(edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard) identical 10 lines
2019-07-14 13:39:26.462 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard W/dcustomkeyboar: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-07-14 13:39:26.484 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-07-14 13:39:26.725 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-07-14 13:39:26.726 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-07-14 13:39:26.727 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-07-14 13:39:26.739 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2019-07-14 13:39:26.739 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd85a7cc0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2019-07-14 13:39:26.758 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd85a7cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc61374e0)
2019-07-14 13:39:26.778 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2019-07-14 13:39:26.785 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/OpenGLRenderer: Setting buffer count to 3, min_undequeued 1, extraBuffers 0
2019-07-14 13:39:26.814 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd85a7cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc61374e0)
2019-07-14 13:39:26.835 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
2019-07-14 13:39:26.944 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd85a7cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc61374e0)
2019-07-14 13:39:26.964 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/OpenGLRenderer: Setting buffer count to 3, min_undequeued 1, extraBuffers 0
2019-07-14 13:39:26.967 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd85a7cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc61374e0)
2019-07-14 13:39:34.439 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/OpenGLRenderer: Setting buffer count to 3, min_undequeued 1, extraBuffers 0
2019-07-14 13:39:34.447 12121-12920/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd85a7cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc61374e0)
2019-07-14 13:39:34.484 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2019-07-14 13:39:34.484 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-07-14 13:39:34.489 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5174)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5131)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
        at edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard.OrthKeyboard$SpeechInnerClass.startVoiceInput(OrthKeyboard.java:201)
        at edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard.OrthKeyboard.onKey(OrthKeyboard.java:85)
        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.detectAndSendKey(KeyboardView.java:847)
        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1354)
        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1217)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13417)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:460)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:861)
        at android.inputmethodservice.SoftInputWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(SoftInputWindow.java:152)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:418)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5282)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4785)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4838)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4804)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4944)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4812)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4785)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4838)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4804)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4812)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4785)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7471)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7432)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7627)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Runti
2019-07-14 13:39:34.489 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-07-14 13:39:34.499 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard, PID: 12121
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5174)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5131)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
        at edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard.OrthKeyboard$SpeechInnerClass.startVoiceInput(OrthKeyboard.java:201)
        at edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard.OrthKeyboard.onKey(OrthKeyboard.java:85)
        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.detectAndSendKey(KeyboardView.java:847)
        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1354)
        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1217)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13417)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:460)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:861)
        at android.inputmethodservice.SoftInputWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(SoftInputWindow.java:152)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:418)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5282)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4785)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4838)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4804)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4944)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4812)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4785)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4838)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4804)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4812)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4785)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7471)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7432)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7627)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
2019-07-14 13:39:34.500 12121-12121/edmt.dev.androidcustomkeyboard E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Code

        }
    });
```

Comment: First of all thank you, but where exactly should I put it/ what part of the code should be inside?

Comment: Find the code that creates the error using try catch and put the code in this method

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please extend your answer so it includes some information on why it would work like this, and how one can apply this fix. In doubt always refer to [answering help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering).